# how to test inline formset

Tags: django, inline-formset, formsets, otree

There is an inline formset that works perfectly well. It fails only in testing.

there is a model that connects two types of participants: senders and receivers.

**`models.py`**:

```
class SendReceive(models.Model):
   receiver =jmodels.ForeignKey(Player, related_name='receiver')
   sender = models.ForeignKey(Player, related_name='sender')
   amount_requested = models.IntegerField()
   amount_sent = models.IntegerField(blank=True)
```

An inline formset is shown to senders, who choose how much to send to receivers:

**`forms.py`**:

```
class SRForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = SendReceive
        fields = ['amount_sent']

SRFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Player, SendReceive,
                                  fk_name='sender',
                                  can_delete=False,
                                  extra=0,
                                  form=SRForm,
                                  )
```

and 
**`views.py (CBV)`**:

```
def post(self):
    context = super().get_context_data()
    formset = SRFormSet(self.request.POST, instance=self.player)
    context['formset'] = formset
    if not formset.is_valid():
        return self.render_to_response(context)
    formset.save()
    return super().post()
```

so, when I try to test it, the line `formset.save()` brings in error:

```
 django.db.utils.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: 
 riskpooling_sendreceive.receiver_id
```

as the receiver id was not set. Although, if I look at the content of the formset.forms which is returned, everything is in there. Again, in the real life everything is ok, and is properly saved. So only testing results in error. What I am doing wrong?

UPDATE:

I do not know if this important or not, but if I compare the output of self.request.POST in a normal flow (without testing) and with testing (the one that ends up with an error:

**with testing:**

```
   <QueryDict: {'sender-0-sender': ['1'], 
   'sender-0-amount_sent': ['6'], 'sender-0-id': ['2'],
    'sender-INITIAL_FORMS': ['1'], 'sender-TOTAL_FORMS': ['1']}>
```

**no testing:**

```
  <QueryDict: {'origin_url': [''], 'sender-INITIAL_FORMS': ['1', '1'], 
  'sender-MAX_NUM_FORMS': ['1000', '1000'], 'csrfmiddlewaretoken': 
   ['KdpMPEJMOR4yHTMyO6KrS1bJE3eMfPBa'], 'sender-0-amount_sent': ['1'], 
   'sender-0-id': ['1'], 'sender-MIN_NUM_FORMS': ['0', '0'],
   'sender-0-sender': ['62'], 'sender-TOTAL_FORMS': ['1', '1']}>
```

so apart from obvious difference in csrf token, everything looks the same.

Comment: In your form the only field is amount_sent. So when you create new object, you are not sending from the to the template the receiver. That is why the error is.

Comment: yes, you are right, but the form updates the record, it does not create one. So by that time receiver is already set.

Comment: hm. What about making the field hidden and add to the fields ?

Answer (score 0):

I've found out what was the reason.

In brief, when you pass the `FORMSET_NAME-0-id` you need to pass there a `pk` of an actual record (if you don't want to create a new one).